# How to write select into @variable at mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have query like this (in phpmyadmin mysql):

```
select id into @ci_id from cities where ci_name='Bandung';
INSERT INTO districts (dis_name, city_id) VALUES ('Batu Kuali',@ci_id);
```

But why data get double in database? i just want one data inserted.

note: i don't use sub query because it will be very long query, and i will execute that very much data.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use sub query or this way, just use `insert select`:

```
INSERT INTO districts (dis_name, city_id)
SELECT 'Batu Kuali', id
FROM cities
WHERE ci_name = 'Bandung';
```

[<kbd>SqlFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c59462/1)

And I think your query is just fine.

Check here [<kbd>demo</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b6b7/1) for your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   declare ci_id int(20) default 0;
   select id into @ci_id from cities where ci_name='Bandung';

     if LENGTH(@ci_id)>0 THEN
              INSERT INTO districts (dis_name, city_id) VALUES ('Batu   Kuali',@ci_id);
   end if;
```